# Oracle 01481. 00000 - "invalid number format model"

Tags: oracle, concatenation, to-char

This is my query i have used to get the value as money. Nut when concat value getting above exception. The query is

```
select to_char(b.balance,'9999.'||d.number_of_decimal_places) from balance b, decimal d
```

Am stuck with this problem.

Comment: What is `number_of_decimal_places` - the number of digits (1, 2, 3...) or a model like 9, 99, 999 ?

Comment: decimal places such as 9, 99, 999

Comment: Can you add the actual table contents to the question? If decimal - which is an invalid table name -  has multiple rows, presumably you have a join condition you haven't shown, so a more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: Can you check that there are no invalid format masks in the `decimal` table?

Comment: is d.number_of_decimal_places a char field having padded spaces that will mess up the mask? Try running select '9999.'||d.number_of_decimal_places from decimal d and see what mask it is actually generating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have numeric `number_of_decimal_places` values like 1, 2, 3 etc. then you are constructing a format model like, for example, `'9999.2'` instead of `'9999.99'`.

You can convert that integer value to the format model with `rpad` or `lpad`:

```
select to_char(b.balance,'9999.'||rpad('9', d.number_of_decimal_places, '9'))
from balance b, decimal d
```

Or for trailing zeros:

```
select to_char(b.balance,'9999.'||rpad('0', d.number_of_decimal_places, '0'))
from balance b, decimal d
```

If you have string `number_of_decimal_places` values like '9', '99', '999' etc. then the concatenation you have will work unless you have an invalid value in one of the rows, which would be any character other than a 9 or a 0.

That includes spaces, which you could have in a `varchar2` or `char` field. Either way you could remove those with `trim`:

```
select to_char(b.balance,'9999.'||trim(d.number_of_decimal_places))
from balance b, decimal d
```

But if you have any other characters then you will need to identify and correct the data in those rows; and even with spaces it would be better to fix the data if it's a `varchar2` column.

---

It would be better to use new-style joins; I haven't changed these examples because it isn't clear if you are doing a cartesian product or have just omitted the join conditions.

Comment: Thanks alex. It work's. But am facing one problem. When am having balance as 0 then the result returns as .00 . Not 0.00. If i using masking as to_number(.....) for 10 and 100 is working. If balance is 1000 it raising an error as "Invalid number". Hope you understand my problem...

Comment: @MuthuVikki - to see '0.00' you need the fixed part to to be `'9990.'`Not sure what you mean about 1000, that's fine with your four-digit fixed mask; more that 10000 will show as hashes though. Neither will give invalid number? You don't have `to_number()` in your question though so don't know quite what you are doing..

Answer (score 0):

If `number_of_decimals` returns a value like `2` then:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( b.balance, RPAD( '9999.', 5 + d.number_of_decimals, '9' ) )
FROM   balance b
       CROSS JOIN
       decimal d
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the concatenation of '9999.'||d.number_of_decimal_places is generating an invalid mask. We can only guess at the actual table values, presence of spaces, or whatever else may be causing issues with what it is doing.

So your solution is to run:

```
select '9999.'||d.number_of_decimal_places from decimal d
```

See what the actual format mask is that you are generating, and adjust as necessary.